# Redirect users to www.url - $_SESSION issue

Tags: php, url, session, redirect, subdomain

**The Issue**

My domain is *www.example.com*. If a user logs in and then closes the tab, then later opens it and goes to *www.example.com*, the session continues absolutely fine, with the user logged in.

However, if they type *example.com* (without the *www.*) then they appear logged out, and if I place `print_r($_SESSION)` nothing comes up. However, clicking any link on the page (redirecting the user to *www.example.com/link*) restores their session.

Therefore I've realised that the user *appears* logged out when they type in *example.com* without the trailing *www* - something that a lot of users (like myself) do regularly.

**The Question**

The two ways I can see of fixing this are either:

- Find a way for the `$_SESSION` to be applicable to any url subdomain (or lack thereof)
- Redirect users who type in *example.com* to *www.example.com*

Are either of these are feasible and, if so, which is the best practice?

Comment: It's very eay to redirect from url.com to www.url.com - you just need to add a few lines to your .htaccess file (assuming you're running Apache). [Here's the first instructional link I found on Google.](http://dense13.com/blog/2008/02/27/redirecting-non-www-to-www-with-htaccess/)

Comment: Thank you. I was also trying to find out if this is best practice or if it would be much better to simply make the session variable work on all subdomains?

Comment: Sorry, I think somebody more knowledgable should reply to the best practices question. :)

Comment: I'd recommend choosing www or non-www throughout your site for this and other reasons.

Comment: But session should expire once user closed the window!

Answer (score 0):

When the session cookie is set, it uses the current domain. But you can configure that this cookie should allow for wildcard domain "*.example.com" instead. That way the session would continue on either url. Be informed that wildcard domain cookies are a little bit unsafer, because they will be sent to ANY subdomain of "example.com" - even those subdomains that you created on some other server. This might not be an issue, but should be mentioned.

But the real fix should be to only have ONE designated domain to be used. Redirect the user to this one domain with a permanent redirect code. That also circumvents the duplicate content issue of search engines (which is not a penalty, but rather the question of "Which of the two URLs should be shown as a search result?").

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The only issue that I could think for the second of your options (ie not using a wildcard domain for the session) is that if there is a mobile version of the site and, say, the user switches to the normal version, would they then be logged out? Can the session be exclusive to just three domains (`example.com`, `www.example.com`, `m.example.com`)?

Comment: You can send three different session cookies manually, if you want. But I doubt that the switching between regular and mobile site will be a very common use pattern. Such a thing should rather be resolved with a permanent "remember-me" token.